# jQuery doesn't work on Notepad++

Tags: jquery, html

I have little problem with simple exercise with jQuery. Code is short so I'll put it whole here:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>fast exercise</title>
    <script scr="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btn1").click(function(){
                $("#main").text("The width of the element is " + $("#main").width() +"px and height is " + $("#main").height() + "px.")
            });
        });

    </script>
    <style>
        #main {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            background: red;
            color: black;
            padding: 30px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            margin: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <button id="btn1">Click here to see basic measurements</button>
        <div id="main">
            <p>This is div called "main"</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm just beginner but I've managed to get some basics. When I'm using button I see no reaction. I use Notepad++ and latest jQuery version. For example when I download same file from website that I'm using to learn it works but if I create it myself it's not. Sorry for such simple problem but it really grinds my gears. Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I tried the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/u2n1v0tq/) and its working..

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: @Swellar You shouldn't change the path to a file in your edit. That itself could be the error.

Comment: Notepad++ ofc sorry

Comment: and a little tip.. put your script before the end of body tag..

Comment: How do you structure those 3 components ( html/ css / js). Can you show your local whole codes, instead of putting in fiddle? Because Fiddle already help you to structure those 3 components, but to do it by physical file, you will need to put in everything manually. For exampl, you will need `<html>`,`<header>`,`<body>` tags in html file

Comment: @Swellar That depends on which edit you click rollback on

Comment: @Weeanerd You got a typo in the script tag, `scr` instead of `src`

Comment: @Swellar OMG I knew that I will make fool of myself in my first question ever, thank you! Problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo in your `script` tag, change `scr`

```
<script scr="jquery.js"></script>
```

to `src`

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```